# In app purchases not selectable in appstoreconnect

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

My new app has four in app purchases (consumables) and I submitted the first version with these IAPs. These IAP's were marked as "Ready for Review". However, the app got rejected due to another reason, and when I uploaded a new build, I couldn't select these IAP's anymore in the app details page, even though they're still "Ready for Review":
[screenshot of the app details page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiy3S.png)

So after resubmitting a new version of the app for review, I got this rejection information:

> We found that your in-app purchase products exhibited one or more bugs when reviewed on iPad running iOS 15.4 on Wi-Fi.

> Specifically, we were not able to buy the in app purchases. The buttons did not react to taps

> Next Steps

> When validating receipts on your server, your server needs to be able to handle a production-signed app getting its receipts from Apple’s test environment. The recommended approach is for your production server to always validate receipts against the production App Store first. If validation fails with the error code "Sandbox receipt used in production," you should validate against the test environment instead.

I tested everything on Testflight before and all the IAP's were working fine. I know that prior to submitting an app with IAP's, these purchases have to be selected on the app details page, so I'm curious why I can't select them and if that's causing the issue.

Right when the app launches, in the AppDelegate, I fetch the products: `IAPManager.shared.fetchProducts()`

and the code for the IAPManager is as follows:

```
final class IAPManager: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

static let shared = IAPManager()
var products = [SKProduct]()
enum Product: String, CaseIterable {
    case firstIdentifier = "com.fahrprueferCreate.tokens_1_1000"
    case secondIdentifier = "com.FahrprueferCreate.tokens_5_4000"
    case thirdIdentifier = "com.FahrprueferCreate.tokens_10_8000"
    case fourthIdentifier = "com.FahrprueferCreate.tokens_20_15000"
    
    var count: Int {
        switch self {
        case .firstIdentifier:
            return 1
        case .secondIdentifier:
            return 5
        case .thirdIdentifier:
            return 10
        case .fourthIdentifier:
            return 20
        }
    }
}
private var completion: ((Int) -> Void)?

// Fetch Product Objects from Apple
func fetchProducts() {
    let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(Product.allCases.compactMap({ $0.rawValue})))
    request.delegate = self
    request.start()
}

// Prompt a product payment transaction
public func purchase(product: Product, completion: @escaping ((Int) -> Void)) {
    guard SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() else {
        // Show some error here
        return
    }
    
    guard let storeKitProduct = products.first(where: { $0.productIdentifier == product.rawValue }) else {
        return
    }
    self.completion = completion
    
    let payment = SKPayment(product: storeKitProduct)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
}

// Observe the transaction state
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    transactions.forEach({ transaction in
        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case.purchasing:
            break
        case .purchased:
            if let product = Product(rawValue: transaction.payment.productIdentifier) {
                completion?(product.count)
            }
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
            break
        case .restored:
            break
        case .failed:
            break
        case .deferred:
            break
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    })
}

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    self.products = response.products
    print("products: ", response.products)
}

func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    guard request is SKProductsRequest else {
        return
    }
    
    print("Product fetch request failed")
}
```

}

Comment: Are your IAPs approved? There may be a disconnect since the first build had issues and the second doesn't know about them. Just call the number or submit a ticket to have them reviewed. You can also put a note when you submit the app or in the rejection notice letting them know what happened. You also need to account for no internet, make sure you are actually getting the products back and then activate the buttons. Test the app having np network connection.

Comment: Thank you for the response - No, the IAP's are not approved and I think there isn't a way to do so prior to submitting an app for review. They're marked as "Ready for Review"

Comment: If you already submitted they should be approved, mention it when you reply to the rejection. But test the behavior offline

Comment: @loremipsum I sent the same version to review again with the remarks and this time, the in app purchases responded, just in a bit a different way: " Specifically, when we tapped on of your in-app purchase products, your app opened the purchase sheet only after some time (about 1-2 minutes). When we entered the password, your app was loading for about 30 seconds and displayed a “Payment failed” error message. " Do you know what's causing the issue here?

Comment: No idea, We would have to see the whole thing, see what is hanging. You might be holding on to the thread somewhere. Make sure you have a `ProgressView` when the app is "working"